# Remove className on input focus

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a multi form using bootstrap.
In my validateForm function I have it so it adds an "Invalid" class if the input value is empty (user hasn't filled anything in)

Upon clicking next, the input gets a reddish background color, indicating the user hasn't filled anything in.

How do I remove the "Invalid" class when either:

- User types something in the input field

OR

- User clicks/focusses on the input field

Thus removing the reddish background color

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm() {
var x, y, i, valid = true;
x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (y[i].value == "") {
        y[i].className += " invalid";
        valid = false;
    }
}
if (valid) { document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish"; }
return valid;
}
```

CSS:

```
        input.invalid {
        background-color: #ffdddd;
    }
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: use `classList.add` and `classList.remove` rather than changing the `className` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: You might find another easy way using the :focus selector.
Read about :focus and :focus-within https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within - perhaps combine it with class names

Comment: Surely you want the "invalid" class to remain on the input until its value is actually valid - otherwise what's the point. An empty string (by definition) is not valid input.

Comment: @Pete Ah right, I've changed it to `y[i].classList.add ("invalid");` - Will try to see if I can figure out how to now call the classList.remove upon focus or w/e

Comment: You can set inputs to be invalid with [`setCustomValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity) and [`reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity). An invalid input automatically prevents form submission. Also, inputs that are invalid (e.g. via `setCustomValidity()`) can be targetted with the [`:invalid` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input").forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener("focus", function(event) {
        input.classList.remove("invalid");
    });
    input.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        input.classList.remove("invalid");
    });
});
```